# Expanding Physical Disk Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: partitioning

So, I've been running out of space with a few instances of Ubuntu 16.04 I spun up. I pretty much gave them the bare minimum at 22-25 GB of data. I also did not setup any of the 3 linux machines with LVM. I'm now struggling to expand the volume /dev/sda1 from the 20ish GB to 32GB of data. Can anyone provide me with some info or assistance on this? I was trying to expand /dev/sda1 with /dev/sda3. I've also setup a VG called LVM.
fdisk -l

```
root@ubuntu-sv2:/home/mwolf# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 32 GiB, 34359738368 bytes, 67108864 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb8b7384e

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048 51380223 51378176 24.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       51382270 52426751  1044482  510M  5 Extended
/dev/sda3       52426752 67108863 14682112    7G 8e Linux LVM
/dev/sda5       51382272 52426751  1044480  510M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have anything important on the LVM physical disk `/dev/sda3`:

1. Turn off swap using `swapoff`.
2. Edit `/etc/fstab` and delete the line referring to the swap partition.
3. Deactivate and remove all LVM logical volumes, volume groups, and physical volumes using `lvchange`, `lvremove`, `vgchange`, `vgremove`, and `pvremove`.
4. Delete partitions `/dev/sda5`, `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda2` in this order.
5. Extend the partition `/dev/sda1`. (For steps 4 and 5 you may use tools such as Gparted or `parted`.)
6. Extend the filesystem on `/dev/sda1` using `resize2fs`. (This may have been done automatically at step 5, depending on what tool you used to extend the partition.)
7. Reboot.
8. Create a swap file and edit `/etc/fstab` to refer to the swap file instead of a swap partition; use `fallocate` and `mkswap` to make the swap file, and `swapon` to start using it without rebooting.

Note: all data on the LVM physical volume `/dev/sda3` will be lost and gone forever. Be certain that you have no data there or you won't ever need it.

Comment: That is not using lvm at all

Comment: @Panther: It is actually *deleting* LVM. The goal of the querent was to extend `/dev/sda1`.

Comment: How do I know if swapoff is turned off? I get this below.